# Template function requires existence of inner class in non-templated class

Tags: c++, templates, nested, definition

There's a template function *f* that requires its template parameter type *T* to have an inner class named *Inner*.

Inside *f* the class *T::Inner* shall be instantiated.

First try.

```
//
// "error: need 'typename' before 'T:: Inner' because 'T' is a dependent scope"   
// 
template <typename T>
void f( void )
{        
    T::Inner i;
}
```

I get that, so here comes the second try, where I don't get what's wrong:

```
/// "error: expected ';' before 'i'
template<typename T> 
void f ( void )
{                        
    typename T::Inner I;
    I i;
}
```

Why is that?

In my understanding:
*Inner* is declared as type.
The template has not yet been instantiated. 
Whether the type *Inner* exists or not first becomes relevant
on instantiation - not definition. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
typename T::Inner i;
```

or

```
typedef typename T::Inner I;
I i;
```

whereas what you have in the question actually declares `I` to be a variable, and then right after that you are trying to use it as though it's a type.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd use `using I = typename T::Inner;` instead. And btw, IMO typename shouldn't be required on the RHS of an `using` statement, where it's clear that the only thing you can have is a type (or, if part of a `decltype`, it's also clear for the compiler what the RHS is).

Comment: @vsoftco write a paper and send it to std-proposals@isocpp.org

Comment: @Brian Hahaha, let me first write a question here. Unfortunately I have other papers to write in my area :) But if I find that it may be a good idea, I'll never say never :)

Comment: @Brian Do you know where can I find some examples of such proposals? Are those the same as the Nxxxx papers, e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html?

Comment: @vsoftco Here is an example: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0222r0.html

Comment: @Brian Thanks, this is very helpful!